# Problems with backup and restore using Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Can someone helps on this issue? I have a scheduled backup and this morning I got this message: “Snapshot of all keyspaces on node {ip address} failed: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)“. I believe nothing was changed before that and now I can backup the database. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the issue with this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/cassandra/data/
```